# Access value of dynamically created text fields

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a web page that asks user to enter number of networks.  Based on number provided by user, it creates corresponding amount of text input fields.  User than enters network addresses in those newly created boxes and when user clicks validate, it pings each networks.

Now, I managed to get the dynamically creation on input fields done but now I am having issue accessing their values.  Please see below code and jsfiddle:

HTML:

```
<div ng-app>
    <div ng-controller="Controller">
        <div class="form-group" id = "numNetDiv" style="display:block">
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <label for="numNetworks">Number of Networks</label>
                <input id="numNetworks" ng-model="numNetworks"
                       ng-change="addNetworkFields()" type="text"
                       class="form-control"  required />
                <div class="col-sm-3" id="container" style="margin-left: 50px"> 
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group" id = "checkNetsDiv" style="display:block">
            <div>
                <button id="checkNets" type="button" class="btn btn-nets"
                        style="margin-left: 100px"
                        ng-click="checkNets()">
                  Validate
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <p id="demo"></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

angularjs:

```
// Add input boxes based on # of networks
function Controller($scope){
    $scope.count=0;
    $scope.addNetworkFields = function() {
    var number = document.getElementById("numNetworks").value;
    console.log(number);
    var container = document.getElementById("container");
    while (container.hasChildNodes()) {
        container.removeChild(container.lastChild);
    }
    for (i=0;i<number;i++){
        container.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Network" + (i+1) + ": "));
        var input = document.createElement("input");
        input.type = "text";
        container.appendChild(input);
        container.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
        }
     }
   // Run ping on each subnet
   $scope.checkNets = function() {
   console.log('Click!')
   var number = document.getElementById("numNetworks").value;
   for (i=0;i<number;i++){
   //Access each networks and run ping on each one after another

   // Call below for each network to perform ping
   var ping = $.param({network: $scope.network[i]}); // [i] to access each network?  Just an idea
   $http({
            url: 'https://' + location.hostname + '/ping_network',
            method: "POST",
            data: ping
        })
        .then(function(response) {
    $scope.pingResult = response.data;
    })

   }
   }

 }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Lwy378ce/137/

I know POST works and the only issue I am having is access each networks one by one and calling that POST on it.  For testing, we can get ride of the whole POST code and replace it with something like console.log(network[i]) and see if console can list all networks.

Thanks
Damon

Comment: You have a great mix here of jQuery with AngularJS which is not recommendable (in this case)

Comment: The AngularJS framework uses a declarative style where the DOM manipulation is done in directives declared in the HTML. It avoids doing DOM manipulation in controllers. Mixing AngularJS directives with DOM manipulation in controllers, makes the app hard to understand, debug, test, and maintain. Try adopting the AngularJS declarative style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be much simpler if you just used a form and the angular js models. You could create your field with ng-repeat, make the ng-model of these input fields the network address and then use those address for the ping. Addresses that would be easily updated when the form is submitted. Also by using ng-show you can hide that validate button until it's useful.

It's also a lot less code.

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('myAppCtrl', function($scope){
 
 $scope.number = 0;
 $scope.addNetworkFields = function(value) {
  $scope.networks = [];
  for(var i = 1; i <= parseInt(value); i++){
   var network = {number : i, address: ""}
   $scope.networks.push(network)
  }
 }
 
  $scope.submit = function() {
    for(var i = 0; i < $scope.networks.length; i++){
      console.log($scope.networks[i].address)
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myAppCtrl as ctrl" ng-cloak layout="column" layout-fill>
  <form  ng-submit="submit()" class="form-group" id = "numNetDiv" style="display:block">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <label for="numNetworks">Number of Networks</label>
      <input id="numNetworks" ng-model="number"
             ng-change="addNetworkFields(number)" type="number"
             class="form-control"  required />
      <div class="col-sm-3" id="container" style="margin-left: 50px">
        <div ng-repeat="network in networks">
          <label>Networks {{network.number}}
          <input ng-model="network.address"
                 type="text" class="form-control" /></label>
        </div>
        <input ng-show="number > 0" type="submit" value="validate"/>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</body>
```

Comment: @georgeawg, thanks! I didn't notice that the input type was wrong when I copied their code.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go: set `id` to each `input` and get it by id later.

```
// Add input boxes based on # of networks
function Controller($scope) {
  $scope.count = 0;
  $scope.addNetworkFields = function() {
    var number = document.getElementById("numNetworks").value;
    console.log(number);
    var container = document.getElementById("container");
    while (container.hasChildNodes()) {
      container.removeChild(container.lastChild);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < number; i++) {
      container.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Network" + (i + 1) + ": "));
      var input = document.createElement("input");
      input.type = "text";
      input.id = "network" + (i + 1);
      container.appendChild(input);
      container.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
    }
  }
  // Run ping on each subnet
  $scope.checkNets = function() {
    console.log('Click!')
    var number = document.getElementById("numNetworks").value;
    for (i = 0; i < number; i++) {
      //Access each networks and run ping on each one after another
      var network = document.getElementById("network" + (i + 1)).value

      // Call below for each network to perform ping
      var ping = $.param({
        network: $scope.network
      });
      $http({
          url: 'https://' + location.hostname + '/ping_network',
          method: "POST",
          data: ping
        })
        .then(function(response) {
          $scope.pingResult = response.data;
        })

    }
  }

}
```